# Zoom problem in Kindle with .MOBI converted from PDF

Tags: calibre, kindle-touch

I have a Kindle Touch (Kindle (7th Generation)). I have converted a PDF into `.MOBI` format using PDF converter tools, such as `kdpdfopt` with all these options set: `-mode fp -n- -c -ocr t -h 6.7in -w 4.7in`. And then, for smooth rendering, I converted this PDF into `.MOBI` using Calibre.

Now when I transferred this converted `.MOBI` file onto my Kindle, the font size remained the same. Even if I try to zoom in, the font size remains constant.

P.S. The font size is set very small which makes reading very poor.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the CSS created by one of your conversion programs is generating a `font-size` attribute that is set absolutely (ie in pixels or points) rather than relatively (ie in ems or percents). Without knowing the details of the tools that you're using, it's unlikely we can give much concrete advice. However, if you can get it into Calibre you can probably produce an epub file, and once you have an epub file you should be able to change the CSS, either through Calibre or manually. Once the epub file is formatted to your liking you can use KindleGen (or Calibre, though I would advise KindleGen instead) to create a mobi file for use on your Kindle Touch.

Comment: I have used the tools such as k2optpdf and calibre.
After reading ur post i converted the pdf in to epub format thru calibre;  the epub format does contain default font size  30 px monospace font magnification step size 20 %.
minimum font size 11 px 

can u give me a proper guideline of how do i convert my pdf into epub format and then using kindlegen i convert into .mobi format.

Comment: So at that point, just change the styling in the CSS file so it's using relative units (eg 2.5em) instead of the absolute ones (30px).